# Is there a simple way to review (not) embedded images within Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Occasionally I have to send out Illustrator files with all images embedded inside the file (same when I receive files from other design companies to edit). Sometimes a link can be missing, meaning the image is not embedded and the image is not present. Is there a quick way to check if I've embedded all placed images inside Illustrator (especially in a file with multiple images and layers) or do I have to check all placed images manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic information covered in the Illustrator help files....

Look at the **Links Panel**.

If there's a tiny image icon on the right, the item is embeded.

[image]

So.. if you are seeking non-embeded images, just look at the links without the icon on the right.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is perfect to review non-embedded images inside the document if needed.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes what I do is package the file instead. it's placed in a folder with a local copy of all linked fonts and images (depending on what you specify in the settings)

http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/package-your-illustrator-cc-file.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try this technique as well. Probably best when I have to send my files including linked images and without outlined text if I understand it correctly